HTML Table is not overflowing its container
I am trying to make an html table overflow its container to have a scrollbar on mobile, but it is not working.
Here's the code:
export default function Stats({ pokemon }: { pokemon: PokemonWithColor }) {
    const { stats, name, color } = pokemon;
    const sum = stats.reduce((sum, stat) => sum + stat.base_stat, 0),
        average = sum / stats.length;

    const pokemonColors = colors[color];
    return (
        <div className="w-full overflow-x-auto">
            <table
                className={`w-full border-collapse border ${pokemonColors.lightBorder} text-left`}
            >
                <caption className="sr-only">{name}&apos;s stats</caption>
                <thead
                    className={
                        pokemonColors.lightBg +
                        " border-b" +
                        pokemonColors.lightBorder
                    }
                >
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" className="px-2 py-1">
                            Stat
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" className="px-2 py-1">
                            Bar
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" className="px-2 py-1">
                            Value
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" className="px-2 py-1">
                            Max
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {stats.map((s, i) => {
                        return (
                            <tr
                                key={s.stat.name}
                                className={
                                    i % 2 === 0 ? pokemonColors.lighterBg : ""
                                }
                            >
                                <th
                                    scope="row"
                                    className="whitespace-nowrap px-2 py-1 capitalize"
                                >
                                    {s.stat.name.replaceAll("-", " ")}
                                </th>
                                <td className="w-full min-w-[250px] px-2 py-1">
                                    <div
                                        className="h-4 rounded bg-black"
                                        style={{
                                            width:
                                                Math.round(
                                                    (s.base_stat /
                                                        pokemonSharedValues.maxStat) *
                                                        100,
                                                ) + "%",
                                        }}
                                    ></div>{" "}
                                </td>
                                <td className="px-2 py-1">{s.base_stat}</td>
                                <td className="px-2 py-1">
                                    {pokemonSharedValues.maxStat}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
                <tfoot className={pokemonColors.lightBg}>
                    <tr className={"border-t " + pokemonColors.lightBorder}>
                        <th scope="row" className="px-2 py-1">
                            Average
                        </th>
                        <td className="w-full min-w-[250px] px-2 py-1">
                            <div
                                className="h-4 rounded bg-black"
                                style={{
                                    width:
                                        Math.round(
                                            (average /
                                                pokemonSharedValues.maxStat) *
                                                100,
                                        ) + "%",
                                }}
                            ></div>
                        </td>
                        <td className="px-2 py-1">{average.toFixed(1)}</td>
                        <td className="px-2 py-1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" className="px-2 py-1">
                            Total
                        </th>
                        <td className="w-full min-w-[250px] px-2 py-1"></td>
                        <td className="px-2 py-1">{sum}</td>
                        <td className="px-2 py-1"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

The table just seems to be scaling the whole page to fit its width (sorry if you didn't understand it, i don't know the best way to describe it). It's really weird. I have tried a lot of approaches, but none of them makes the table overflow and the scrollbar appear.
What i am trying to achieve can be seen here: pokemondb pikachu page. Scroll down to the base stats table and resize the window. You can see that a scrollbar appears when the screen is small enough.
I even tried to copy what they did, but it didn't work as well. I don't see what is not working here. I tested the responsiveness of the table and when the table reaches the point where the min-wdith of the table cells begin to have an effect, the table seems to scale the whole page to fit its width.

It is difficult to say what is happening there, so I advise blindly: set html { overflow-x: hidden; }
